# Multiple SQL WITH clauses - why not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I had 2 separate queries.

Query 1:

```
With A as (Select P,Q,R from X union all Select P,Q,R from Y)
Insert into File1
Select * from A
```

Query 2:

```
With B as (Select S,T,U from Z)
Insert into File2
Select * from B
```

I realised that,logically, I always need to produce File1 and File2 together, so I decided to just merge the 2 queries into one Stored Procedure. However, when I tried to do it, I hit this problem where it's only possible to have one WITH clause in a query.

So, I found a few questions in SO where people explained that you just use a comma and have a separate WITH clause (albeit, without the WITH) but this wouldn't work in any form for my example.

It wasn't a problem - I've easily worked around it by using temporary tables etc. But I'm really intrigued as to why I can't have two entirely unrelated WITH clauses in the same Proc?

Can anyone explain please?

Comment: Trying to merge into a single query is different to making a single stored procedure. Maybe you could post your actual code, and the actual error to allow us to assist you.

Comment: It's not that `it's only possible to have one WITH clause in a query`, just that before using `WITH` you need to end the previous command with a semicolon...that's it. Or just add a semicolon to the beginning of the `WITH`: `;WITH B....`

Comment: and with this sample, you don't need CTE's at all. Just do normal inserts

Comment: @Lamak Thank you. I think I tried that but I will try again and report back.

Comment: You can have multiple CTEs with a single statement (With FirstCTE AS (SELECT blah blah), SecondCTE AS (Select blah, bah) SELECT * from FirstCTE INNER JOIN SecondCTE ON blah, blah...   What you CANNOT do is have multiple statements refer to the same CTE. The duration and scope of a CTE (or CTEs) is exactly one statement (whether INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, MERGE, etc)

Comment: @scsimon This is a greatly simplified version of the 2 individual queries, I was really just using the code to point out that the results of the queries are entirely unrelated, but both of the outputs feed into a common process.

Comment: Just wondering - the code you posted doesn't seem to *need* common table expressions at all - you could simply do an `insert...select` with the `select` statement used for the common table expression... I realize that it's probably an over simplified example, but still - I would consider that option.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, see my comment above - the code I posted was simply to properly illustrate that the 2 CTEs were entirely unrelated. In examples I found on SO, people were trying to use dependent or nested CTEs so I was trying to make sure people didn't answer the wrong question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to have 2 WITH clauses, you just need a semicolon after the first one.

```
With A as (Select P,Q,R from X union all Select P,Q,R from Y)
Insert into File1
Select * from A;


With B as (Select S,T,U from Z)
Insert into File2
Select * from B
```

This is the error you would get from SQL if you are trying to do two without semicolon:

```
Msg 336, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'B'. If this is intended to be a common table expression, you need to explicitly terminate the previous statement with a semi-colon.
```

Comment: Yes, that's the error I was getting. One of the other answers on SO explicitly mentioned the use of the semicolon, but when I tried it, it wouldn't work. I got the sense that there was some very deep reason why you would never need to use WITH clauses in the same query, hence my question.

Comment: Having just scrolled to the right of the error message, I'm now feeling pretty stupid!

Comment: Just recreated the merged queries as I did before - but this time with a couple of semicolons in place. Worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: @Lefty From [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "`;` Transact-SQL statement terminator. Although the semicolon is not required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be required in a future version." Make it a habit to use it.

Comment: @HABO Thanks for that tip - I think it will save me many problems in the future!